# TextBox appears inset when Enabled=false;

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I'm running vb.net with vs2012.  I have various `CheckBoxes` that `Enable` and `Disable` `TextBoxes`.  I've noticed that if a user has their cursor in the `TextBox` (when Enabled), and then `click` the `CheckBox` to `Disable` the `TextBox`, the `TextBox` appears inset.  This only occurs when the cursor is in the `TextBox` while the user clicks the `CheckBox` to `Disable` the `TextBox`.

I also noticed that if I throw up a message box right before the `TextBox`is `Disabled`, the `TextBox` does NOT appear inset; I assume because the focus has changed.  Because of this, I tried setting the focus to another control before disabling the `TextBox`, however, this does not work.  Is there anyway I can get around this so that my `TextBox`do not appear inset when a user disables them while having their cursor in the box?

Thanks!

Comment: Which OS? I do not see what you describe on Windows 7 x64 using VS2012. Have you tried setting the TextBox's BorderStyle to BorderStyle.FixedSingle? In the project properties, do you have "Enable XP visual styles" checked?

Comment: I'm not sure how to set this as the answer, but if I set the border style to FixedSingle instead of Fixed3D, the problem does not appear.  I believe this is a VS 2012 bug.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I have to post it as an answer instead of a comment so that you can set it as the answer, so I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `Textbox.enabled=False` it will appear but if you will set `Textbox.Visible=False` it wont appear

Comment: enabled=false means it is visible but you cant use it

Comment: yes i'm aware of this, this is not the problem, however.  the textbox behaves the way it's supposed to, the issue is that when a user disables the textbox while a cursor is active inside the textbox (by checking a checkbox), the textbox is disabled but appears inset, and different from all of the other disabled textboxes.

Comment: You are using Visual Basic 2012 ?
That can be a bug

Comment: The answer is above, I've set the borders to FixedSingle instead of Fixed3d and the problem does not appear.  I believe this is a VS2012 bug.

Comment: For the record, if you'd like to replicate this.  Create a windows form project with a textbox and a checkbox, have the checkbox enable and disable the textbox based on checked value.  Place cursor in the enabled textbox, check the checkbox to disable the textbox, and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the TextBox's BorderStyle to `BorderStyle.FixedSingle` then you should get the behaviour you're looking for.